# Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data.Unsupported field value: a function (found in field dispatch)"

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I'm trying to build a web app with vue, vuex and trying to integrate it with the firebase database. But this error pops up when i try to post data into the database:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]:
Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value:
a function (found in field dispatch)" found in 
---> <Subreddit> at src/views/Subreddit.vue
   <App> at src/App.vue
     <Root>
```

The script code inside the module "Subreddit.vue" is:

```html
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  data: () => ({
    post: {
      title: '',
      description: '',
      URL: '',
    },
  }),
  computed: mapState('subreddit', ['posts']),
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('subreddit', ['createPost']),
    async onCreatePost() {
      if (this.post.title && (this.post.description || this.post.URL)) {
        await this.createPost(this.post);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This is the subreddit.js from the store directory in which the createPost() is written, inside the actions,

```js
import db from '@/db';

const posts = db.collection('posts');

const state = {
  posts: [],
};

const actions = {
  async createPost(post) {
    console.log(post); // eslint-disable-line no-console
    const result = posts.doc();
    post.id = result.id; // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
    await posts.doc(post.id).set(post);
  },
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  actions,
};
```

The output for `console.log(post)` from `createPost(post)` is too long but this is it:

```js
{getters: {…}, state: {…}, rootGetters: {…}, dispatch: ƒ, commit: ƒ, …}
commit: ƒ (_type, _payload, _options)
dispatch: ƒ (_type, _payload, _options)
getters: {}
id: "VassMHMvvK2UlfS79bDp"
rootGetters: {}
rootState: {__ob__: Observer}
state: {__ob__: Observer}
__proto__: Object
```

What is the error, i am not able to debug it.

Comment: You should share the `createPost` method content.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec okay, please check question again.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see what does `this.createPost(this.post)`... Your error message indicates that "Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data.". If we don't see where this `set()` method is called, we cannot help you.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec please check the question again, i've just uploaded the code for `this.createPost(this.post)`

Comment: Can you show what is the exact value of `post` that you pass to `set()`, in `await posts.doc(post.id).set(post);`. Can you pls show the output of a `console.log(post)`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec the output is a json object but it is too long so i copied a minimized version of it from the console. Please check the question again.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of the `set()` function shall be "a map of the fields and values for the document", as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set).

From your question, it appears that you pass an object that does not respect this constraint.

```
{getters: {…}, state: {…}, rootGetters: {…}, dispatch: ƒ, commit: ƒ, …}
commit: ƒ (_type, _payload, _options)
dispatch: ƒ (_type, _payload, _options)
getters: {}
id: "VassMHMvvK2UlfS79bDp"
rootGetters: {}
rootState: {__ob__: Observer}
state: {__ob__: Observer}
__proto__: Object
```

This is exactly what the error message indicates: `DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data`.

So you should adapt your object in such a way it is a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of the fields and values for the document.

For example:

```
const obj = {foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'};
await posts.doc(post.id).set(obj);
```

Comment: thankyou for the answer. I understand that the `.set()` needs a valid object as a parameter in order to execute and the `.doc()` needs a valid string as a parameter. The issue is that the value of the post object that i have displayed in the question is not what i want. In the `Subreddit.vue` script code, when the `onCreatePost()` gets called on click, it should pass the form data to the post object and that should be passed as a parameter to `this.createPost(this.post)` . i don't understand how to get that data in that function.

Answer (score 0):

I've Solved the Problem. For some reason, even if the attributes in a collection aren't explicitly defined as ' required', the post operation will not work unless the complete object is passed to the firestore database. I might be wrong but after trying everything and failing and just deciding to continue coding the project, the error just vanished away. The code is available on my [GitHub](https://github.com/DivineDemon/reddit-clone) if you need to check it out. Thankyou for all your help.